# How can I make a loop to repeat my method for each item?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

there is my issue. In a controller, I have this method which export my view in a file when I click a button.

```
public ActionResult Export(string searchString, int searchOrder = 0)
{
    var user = from m in db.Orders select m;

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
    {
        user = user.Where(s => s.ClientID.Contains(searchString));
    }

    Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/vnd.ms-excel");            
    return this.View(user);
}
```

My Index view :

```
@model IEnumerable<MyApp.Models.Order>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Orders Historic</h2>    

<div id="orderDiv">
@using (Html.BeginForm("Export", "Historic", FormMethod.Get))
{
            <p>
        Generate Order with ClientID :&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
         @Html.TextBox("searchString")

        <input type="submit" value="GENEREMOI" />
        </p>
}
</div>
```

And my Export view :

```
@model IEnumerable<KrysGroup.Models.Order>

    <table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3">
        <tr>       
            <td width="12%" align="center">
                Client Name/ID
            </td>
            <td width="15%" align="center">
                N° Order
            </td>

            OTHER TD....

        </tr>   

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
      TimeSpan result = DateTime.Now - item.OrderDate;

      if (result.Days < 31)
      {            
            <tr border="1" bgcolor="@Odd">
               <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Username) </td>    
               <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.OrderId) </td>  
                <td>
                    <ul style="list-style-type:none; padding:0; margin:0">
                        @if (item.OrderDetails != null)
                        {
                            foreach (var o in item.OrderDetails)
                            {
                                if (o.Pack == null)
                                { 
                                    <li>  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => o.Product.Name)  </li>
                                }
                                else
                                {  
                                    <li> <text>Pack</text>  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => o.Pack.Name)  </li>
                                }
                            }
                        }  
                    </ul>             
                </td>

                OTHER TD...    
 </table>
```

So, in my view, I inform in a textbox a ClientID and when I click the button, it export in a file all the fields in my table with this ClientID.

I would like to automate this action, that is to say I would like write a method or something for, when I click on the button, it executes this export() method for each clientId it meet in my table.

I hope I was clear enough, sorry for my english..
Thanks for your answers, links, tips whatever.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you are trying to achieve. Do you want to apply the above function a list of ids? Or do you want to automate the click itself with some sort of event?

Comment: Second one. In fact, I would automate the following actions : 1-Enter ID. 2-Click button to export. And do it again for the next ID, and again for the next. Is it more clear ?   If by "apply the above function to a list of ids" you means, retrieves all ClientID in a list, and then when my enduser click, it executes this method for all ID in my list, I thinks it could be what I want... But I need it works dynamcally

Answer (score 0):

You can write a partial view typed to a list of Id's that loads when you click the button.

So in the controller you have a method converts what you want and returns a view that is typed to the conversion of your model.

In your main view you have a div that will be populated with a partial view after the click-event of the original button.

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Name", "NameOfTheAction", "NameOfTheController",
                                   new { id = itemId },
                                   new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Get", UpdateTargetId = "divInMainView", OnSuccess = "Do Something (js)" },
                                    new { html-props })
```

How to populate is up to you, in your view

Comment: Why should I write a partial view ? Why I can't write this foreach condition directly in my méthod ? If I well understood what you said, I must write a partial view with my export method inside for each id, and then I call it from my controller ? Sorry I'm beginner in asp and mvc, and I never write a partial view with binding of data.

Comment: With that I mean that in your controller you have an action that you can call from the view. This action returns you a (partial)view.
So in your main view you can bind a function to the click event on the button, that fills a div with the result (the partial view) of the action you just called in the controller. I hope this made some sence.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I think I've already this partial view... My Export View ( I've updated my post ). Is my Export View is the partial View you mentioned ? About your reply, I understood that, in my Index view (main view in your words) I call my Export method/action. This action returns me my Export view (that is to say partial view in your words ?)

Comment: If you mean that your main page (index) calls an export method in the controller to populate a div in the main page(index) with a partial view (export) you are right.
In that partial page you can write a loop that goes over all of the id's you pass through.

Comment: In fact, like I said in my question, it generates a xls file from my ExportView. So, my method do not populate a div in the main page, but it populate a div, more precisely an array in my ExportView. Can I write the loop in this view ? Because like you can see, in this view I've already several foreach loop...

Comment: Write a loop in ExportView will not doing what I want. It's the action I need to repeat, in fact the best will be that, at the end, I've several xls files.

Comment: I think you can, but then you have to write your javascriptcode (in which you call the exportmethod) in the partial view. Because when it refreshes one time, the code in your index view won't recognise the divs in your export because they have been reloaded.
Hope this helps you a bit.

Comment: Or let the loop run in the controller;
so click => controller generates all the xls needed and returns view => model (xls's) populate view

Comment: Ok thanks, it's still a bit blur but I'll try somes things before come back. And i'm totally incompetent in js so, I'll work on your second reply

Comment: Edited my original post.
Hope it will help a bit.

Comment: I've read some article on partial view and I studied your answer, I think the partial view is not an option for me, cause I don't display my export view in a "normal" view. Actually, when I click the link, it retrieves me a file, not a view. The file is based on my view, but that's it. My view just serves as a model to format my data. I really need to execute several time my entire method for each ClientID in my table. That is to say, at the end, I must have serveral file by clicking once on the link. So I'm still searching. I really don't know js that why, maybe, I can't see what you mean

Comment: Try reading up about Ajax/Javascript, sorry I couldn't provide any other help!

Comment: Thanks anyway, you gave me some paths to follow, what I'll do.

Comment: Were you able to solve your problem?
If so, how did you do it?

Comment: Not yet unfortunately, I'm always stuck. I tried to write a function who call my Export method for each ClientID in a list, but it doesn't works either. I tried some things with ajax/js but again, nothing works. Like my method is an ActionResult which return a view, at least in some way, it return a file based on this view, I can not implement a function which return several view. Well, I don't know, i'm still looking for a solution of any kind. Thanks for asking, i will post my solution if I find one